# Why is the cavaquinho minhoto so different from other cavaquinhos?

Tags: history, string-instruments

For context: [cavaquinho](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Cavaquinho)

The Brazilian cavaquinho, the cavaquinho de Lisboa, the Cabo Verde cavaquinho, the Madeiran braguinha and its descendant, the ukulele, all seem to have a fretboard that is raised above the body and goes till the edge of the soundhole, like in many other instruments, including the classical guitar. The fretboard of a cavaquinho minhoto, on the other hand, is on the same level as the body and ends where the body begins. Often a cavaquinho minhoto has additional unusual features that I haven't seen in other cavaquinhos, e.g. "fan-like" Preston tuners like those of the Portuguese guitar, "boca de raia" soundhole like that of the viola braguesa, the soundboard consisting of two parts with the upper part made of a different kind of wood

Why is the cavaquinho minhoto today so different from other cavaquinhos and how did they diverge?

[image: cavaquinho minhoto]

[image: cavaquinho minhoto]

More illustrations: https://cavaquinhos.pt/cavaquinho-modelos

Comment: It doesn't seem to answer the question, but https://cavaquinho-minhoto.blogspot.com/2009/05/cavaquinho-by-dr-ernesto-veiga-de.html is one of few detailed sources in English. One line appears to attest that the minhoto existed as early as 1765 (the reference to the *Macarronea*).

Comment: @AndyBonner Interesting, "machinha". It might be related to "machete" (another name for braguinha)

Comment: The fingerboard being level with the top is quite usual for baroque lute and guitar like instruments.